# Application of the principle of conservation of angular momentum and the principle of conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, satellites

I came across this question and was left confused.

A satellite is launched in a direction parallel to the surface of the earth with a velocity of $36900 \; \mathrm{\frac{km}{hr}}$ from an altitude of $500 \; \mathrm{km}$. Determine the maximum allowable error in the direction of launching if the satellite is to go into orbit and come no closer than $200 \; \mathrm{km}$ to the surface of the earth.

I got confused because when the direction of velocity is parallel to the surface of the earth then the direction of velocity is also perpendicular to the radius vector. Then from the principle of conservation of angular momentum

$$r_1 m v_1 \sin \phi_1 = r_2 m v_2 \sin \phi_2$$

where
$r =$ distance of the satellite from the center of the earth,
$m =$ mass of the satellite,
$v =$ velocity of the satellite, and
$\phi =$ the angle the velocity makes with the radius vector.

The altitude of the satellite is either maximum or minimum. This means that $500\; \mathrm{km}$ is either a minimum or maximum altitude of the satellite. After using the principle of conservation of energy I figured that $500\; \mathrm{km}$ was the minimum altitude but despite that I am given $200 \;\mathrm{km}$ which also seems to be the minimum altitude (I mean how can we have two minimum altitudes). Can someone please tell me what's going on?

Comment: The way I would read the question is that the satellite is *supposed* to be launched parallel to the surface, but there is some error in that direction. So it will be launched slightly up or slightly down, and you should find the maximum allowable deviation from that perfectly parallel launch such that the minimum altitude of the orbit is no less than 200 km.

Comment: Thanks noah your explanations have enlightened me. Would you mind now telling me how to obtain the error

Comment: A straight up solution to a homework problem is off-topic here. But if you have any conceptual questions someone might be happy to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the given velocity and altitude, you can use conservation of energy to find the velocity at the point of nearest approach.  (This will be parallel to the surface.)  Then you can use conservation of angular momentum to find the (error) angle (measured from the parallel to the surface) at the launch point.